# How can a function be added to the globals list for the eval function?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def printMeToo(val):
    print(val)

z = 'This is amazing'
expression = 'printMeToo(z)'
eval(expression)

# This eval fails
myGlobals = {'z':z}
eval(expression, myGlobals)
```

[image: This is the runtime error]

Comment: `myGlobals = {'printMeToo': printMeToo}`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Not kind.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you, that was not my intention at all. I removed that comment. I simply meant that it looks like you're aware of the fact that passing a dict serves as the globals for the eval, so I was wondering why are you surprised if `z` is there and `printMeToo` is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that on the second call you override globals, hence `printMeToo` isn't there anymore. Try:

```
>>> myGlobals = {'z': z, 'printMeToo': printMeToo}
>>> eval(expression, myGlobals)
This is amazing
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the function to the myGlobals variable.

```py
myGlobals = {'printMeToo':printMeToo, "z":z}
eval(expression, myGlobals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `printMeToo` in the globals otherwise eval would just allow the `__builtins__` and the `z`

```
def printMeToo(val):
    print(val)

z = 'This is amazing'
expression = 'printMeToo(z)'
eval(expression)

myGlobals = {'z':z,'printMeToo':printMeToo}
eval(expression, myGlobals)
```